# How to access archieved items in Orgmode

Tags: org-mode

I recently started to use the archive option in orgmode. However, I found difficult to find accesible the file to which items get archived. It seems to be a hidden file. Could this be changed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location of the archive file by customizing the `org-archive-location` option.  Run <kbd>C-h v</kbd> and enter "org-archive-location" to see more information about this variable.  Here's one example from its docstring: To store the entries as top-level headings in "~/org/archive.org", you could set this variable to

```
(setq org-archive-location "~/org/archive.org::")
```

You can also find more information in the Org manual: `(info "(org)Archiving")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is not the where, but the fact that the file is hidden (!).

Comment: but isn't the fact that the file is hidden related to its name and/or location, and wouldn't choosing a file which name and location make it visible (e.g. on the desktop) solve the issue?